# python 2.7.8 TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I am trying to fetching data from sqllite db which has data. But i dont know why this is throwing error. This  `D = self.con.execute('select length from googlepagelength where urlid = {0}'.format(row[0])).fetchone()[0]`  is printing 3 values but on next iteration it gives error.

**code:**

```
def bm25scoreresultsfromGoogle (self, rows, wordids, k = 2.0, b = 0.75):
        # Find total number of documents in the collection
        #print 'row',rows
        #print 'wordids',wordids
        N = self.con.execute ('select count(*) from googleurllist').fetchone()[0]
        N = float(N)
        # Find the length for all documents in collection (not only the retrieved ones)
        ids = [id for id in self.con.execute ('select rowid from googleurllist')]
        alldoclengths = dict([(id[0], self.con.execute ('select length from googlepagelength').fetchone()[0]) for id in ids])
        # Calculate avgdl (average doc length)
        avgdl = 0.0
        for i in range(len(alldoclengths)):
            avgdl += alldoclengths.values()[i]
        avgdl = avgdl*1/len(alldoclengths)
        scores = dict([(id[0], 0.0) for id in ids])
        # Calculate |D| -> Document length
        i=0
        #print 'row',rows
        for row in rows:
            i=i+1
            #print i,'rowww',row[1]
            D = self.con.execute('select length from googlepagelength where urlid = {0}'.format(row[0])).fetchone()[0] # error appearing
            #print 'D',D  # 

            tempscore = 0.0
            for wordid in wordids:
                wordfreq = self.con.execute('select count (*) from googlewordlocation where urlid = %i and wordid = %i' %(row[0], wordid)).fetchone()[0]
                print 'wf',wordfreq
                num = wordfreq*(1.0 + k)
                den = b*D*1/avgdl
                den += (1.0 - b)
                den *= k
                den += wordfreq
                # Calculate the right part of the equation
                rscore = num*1/den
                # Find number of documents containing wordid
                nq = self.con.execute('select distinct urlid from googlewordlocation where wordid = %i' %wordid)
                nq = len([id for id in nq])
                # Calculate IDF
                IDF = log10((N - nq + 0.5)*1/(nq + 0.5))
                tempscore += IDF*rscore
            scores[row[0]] = tempscore
            #print 'IDF',scores[row[0]]
        return self.normalizescores(scores)
```

Error:

```
in bm25scoreresultsfromGoogle
    D = self.con.execute('select length from googlepagelength where urlid = {0}'.format(row[0])).fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

is anything which i am doing wrong?

Comment: print out `row` and and `self.con.execute('select length from googlepagelength where urlid = {0}'.format(row[0])).fetchone()`, is one of them `None`?

Comment: You're trying to get a value from a None object (null, not a valid object), which is throwing you off. I would assume it prints 3 values since that's all that available, while the next one returns none and the default value is None. Try to check for a valid object, split the functions that return a value and 'if x:' to check if the value is not None

Comment: Your expressions are too complex, which makes it very hard to debug. The way that line is written, there is no way to know if the thing that is None is `row` or the result of `fetchone()`. Break it up into separate statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 10.5.8 MySQLCursor.fetchone() Method
>
> This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available. By default, the returned tuple consists of data returned by the MySQL server, converted to Python objects. If the cursor is a raw cursor, no such conversion occurs; see Section 10.6.2, “cursor.MySQLCursorRaw Class”.
>
> source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html

You're trying to retrieve information from a NoneType since the function returns that when no more rows are available. (You reach the ending of your query results)

A quick, but ugly 'fix':

```
D = self.con.execute('select length from googlepagelength where urlid = {0}'.format(row[0])).fetchone()
if D:
    D = D[0]
```

This would fail afterwards since D is no the same type you're expecting(if any), hence why I don't recommend to use this code directly but just as a reference of how to fix the error.